# What is the proper way to include code from an external file in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been using PHP for years to build websites.  Often I will use an include to bring in, say a navigation menu:

```
<?php include 'includes/nav.php'; ?>
```

I am much more of a novice when it comes to ASP.NET (C#).  I am wondering what is the correct (and most efficient) way of doing the equivalent of a PHP include, in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably the most analogous ASP.NET construct to PHP's include, based on your example, is [creating and referencing a user control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53.aspx). This allows you to predefine markup as well as any server-side functionality in an ASCX file, which you can use into your page.

You can also [use a master page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx), as someone stated below, which flushes out your basic layout and lets you define content place holders, which other pages can implement and fill in the content. Master pages are a popular approach for defining page elements that are consistent across all pages, like your nav there (also things like headers, footers, common scripts, CSS, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

One way accomplish this is by using [Master Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx)

You define layouts and "pin-points" on these layouts.

Another way is using [User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). You put markup in a separate file (*.ascx) and then reference it in pages or master pages (this is more like include).

I advise you, in the most polite way, to read a book about ASP .Net.

Comment: +1 Also note that you can, of course, embed user controls in a master page, so you don't have to fill your master page with tons of markup.

Comment: @dash, sure, that too ( I've edited the answer to specify this also)

Comment: Totally agree on the book and thanks for the info.  I think User Controls was what I was thinking of.  I had used them on a site a couple of years ago but had someone more knowledgeable than me tell me that wasn't the correct way to "include" content into a site, but he didn't go into detail.  So I thought I was doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the role that the include file plays. Reusable bits of content can be created as User Controls, or it might form part of a Master Page.

Have a look at this article: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/144/Classic-ASP-Include-Files-in-ASP.NET

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reference and use a control.

```
<%@ Register Src="includes/Nav.ascx" TagPrefix="uc" TagName="Nav" %>
```

You can later add the control on your page.

```
<uc:Nav ID="navMenu" runat="server" />
```

If you want to reference a namespace to use in a code block `<% code here %>`

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Includes.Nav" %>
```

Comment: Your answer duplicates existing answers, but I didn't downvote since yours is the only one that shows the syntax.

Comment: I have a bad habit of that:  I start to answer, then get distracted and only come back a few minutes later. :-(

Comment: Downvoting for duplicates provokes the bad practice of throwing in a short placeholder answer to edit it with details later just to be the first. I don't care if I will be downvoted but why punish people who take the time to find out more details or test the code they post?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really include code as text this way.  ASP.NET operates on classes and assemblies.  Depending on how you are building your asp and what you are attempting to do.  You can add a reference to a dll or drop the class in the special classes folder.  If you are attempting to share layout the use a master page is common.

Comment: The most common use I would have would be in the aforementioned include of a nav menu or footer that will be repeated ALMOST everywhere.

Comment: Use a master page it shares lay out and functionality with all the content pages.

Comment: I've used a Master Page on one site and while it worked OK I am primarily a Dreamweaver user and unlike Visual Studio that "sucks in" the master page, if you open a page in DW that has a master page, you just get an unformatted page which is hard to deal with when you are trying to manipulate the graphical interface.

Comment: Then I would create a user control that is your nav and use that.  I have never used dream weaver so I don't know what its capabilities are.  Also in VS very complicated master pages are also often not viewable in the editor so its always kinda a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have no experience with PHP and I am making some assumptions based on what I know.

In a regular C# file (including ASP.NET Web Forms code behind file or ASP.NET MVC controller) there is the using statement that imports a namespace. It looks like this:

```
using ParentNamespace.ChildNamespace;
```

This allows you to use classes in the ChildNamespace without typing the full name of the class ParentNamespace.ChildNamespace.SomeClass. Keep in mind that before doing this you must add a reference to the assembly (usually DLL file) in the references of your project (managed via the References kind-of folder in Visual Studio). A single assembly can have multiple namespaces and classes and there are some assemblies added by default in standard project templates.

In an ASP.NET Web Forms project you can reference what is called [user controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53.aspx). User controls are encapsulated view + code behind much like your page that are really easy to reuse. You reference the control on the top of your page (or control) like this:

```
<%@ Register src="~/Folder/Subfolder/MyControl.ascx" tagname="MyCustomControlName" tagprefix="myCustomPrefix" %>
```

and then at the place where you want your control you use it like this:

```
<myCustomPrefix:MyCustomControlName ID="myControl" runat="server" />
```

In ASP.NET MVC you can reference namespaces with using in code blocks (the syntax depends on the view engine you are using but it is something with using) and you can reuse other views by calling the Html.RenderPartial method like this:

```
Html.RenderPartial("MyCustomView");
```

Another way to get kind of reverse reference around a page are [Master Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx). They allow you to define place holders for the content of your page.

Comment: So you are downvoting me because I took the time to write more complete answer? As it happens SOME parts of my answer duplicate existing answers but please point out what answer mentions how to do things in MVC or in code behind?

Comment: Considering that the OP is asking about nav controls, the part of your answer on the using declaration does not apply. Considering that he didn't even mention mvc, that part is not relevant either. What's left is a duplicate of existing answers. Please edit your answer so I can remove the downvote. I now think these comments are sufficient.

Comment: He doesn't make a reference to Web Forms either. Why do you assume he is not using MVC?

Comment: [so] won't let me remove the downvote unless you edit your answer. Do some trivial eded hten I can remove it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders you can edit it by yourself..(formatting), I believe you can undo the edit after..